# Can't use node fs module with k6

Tags: javascript, load-testing, k6

I have followed the instructions [here](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/modules) and have setup webpack, but still couldn't use fs module to read the file.

Note: I am aware of open() function provided by k6 to read file but i want to check if the file exists before reading, because open() function throws go runtime error if file does not exist.

Comment: Why can't you use `fs`?  What went wrong? Where's the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a native node module like `fs` isn't supported.

What you should probably use is a function wrapper around `open` to check if a file exists:

```js
function exists(name) {
  try {
    open(name);
    return true;
  } catch(e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

It is important also to note that [open is only supported in the init context](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/issues/557#issuecomment-376115100) so you can't use it inside the default function.
So if this is some integral part of your test you should probably rethink how it's done.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped. yes i am using it in the init context only.